# MS SQL Server data lost or corrupted

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, data-recovery

I have a situation regarding MS SQL Server database.

My friend ask me to repair a certain database, because a range of data has been lost after a hard disk failure, but eventually after troubleshooting, swapping the data cables of the two HDD with software RAID 1 configuration, the hard disk has been restore and operational, but, unfortunately, a range of data is nowhere to be found.

Question: What do you think happened to the data? corrupted?
The data has been corrupted when the hard disk failed? Can I recovered that data?

MS SQL Server 2000
MS Windows Server 2003 R2

Thanks.

Comment: Could have been corrupted, or lost. You would have to provide more detail in order for us to help you.

Comment: The database has the data from April  1 to  30. May 1, the server encountered a problem, blue screen and a hard disk failure. After troubleshooting and the server become available, the data from April 1 to 30 disappeared...

Update: The company's IT Specialist manage to recovered the lost data. Is it possible to recovered a lost data without the backup file? THanks

Comment: Ask how he did it, and post it here as an answer. :) I'd vote you up.

Comment: @Konrad Gajewski, Yes, I would vote for it too... :)